# How do I convert my current linux installation into squashfs live image with persistent changes

Tags: docker, backup, squashfs

My goal is to convert a raspbx server into a docker container. Something like this [how to convert an iso to a docker image](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-convert-an-iso-to-a-docker-image/)

So, how can I make my current raspbx installation into a squashfs file system iso, which will contain "filesytem.squashfs".

Comment: The linked instructions converts a `squashfs` image into a `tar` archive, which is then imported into Docker.  You should be able to skip the `squashfs` step and just make a `tar` archive of your current filesystem to import into Docker.

Comment: Will try that, and report back. But my previous attempts show docker skipping socket files. Is there a specific way to make a tar file that will work with docker?